# Conditional split of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Given a DataFrame that looks like this

```
Index   Time               Val 
1       2017-06-29 17:48    0
2       2017-06-29 17:49    0
3       2017-06-29 17:50    1
4       2017-06-29 17:51    2
5       2017-06-29 17:52    3
6       2017-06-29 17:53    0
7       2017-06-29 17:54    0
8       2017-06-29 17:55    0
9       2017-06-29 17:56    0
10      2017-06-29 17:57    0
```

How can I split it into two **lists** of dataframes where one list is the blocks where `val == 0` and one is the blocks where `val > 0` (`val < 0` does not occur). However, there is the following complication. When `val > 0`, the next time `val == 0` should start a new data frame and vice versa.

So based on the data frame above, the first list would contain two dataframes: one containing indexes 1-2 and one containing the indexes 6-9. The second list should contain one dataframe of indexes 3-5.

I know I can strip out the `val > 0` lines by doing `df[df.val == 0]` which would give the data frame below, but because of the break between indexes 2 and 6, I need them in different data frames.

```
Index   Time               Val 
1       2017-06-29 17:48    0
2       2017-06-29 17:49    0
6       2017-06-29 17:53    0
7       2017-06-29 17:54    0
8       2017-06-29 17:55    0
9       2017-06-29 17:56    0
10      2017-06-29 17:57    0
```

N.B. This needs to scale to a large data frame (millions of rows) so speed is desirable. Going through each row and looking for a break in the indexes (or timestamps) is not preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot guarantee that the following will run fast, but it should get you pretty far. The idea behind this is the use of what is known as `run-length encoding` on the `Val` column to generate a new column by which to group your dataframe. The following should serve as a decent start:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
from itertools import groupby
from functools import reduce


d = {'Time': [Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:48:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:49:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:50:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:51:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:52:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:53:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:54:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:55:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:56:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:57:00')],
 'Val': [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['grouper'] = reduce(list.__add__, ([x]*len(list(y[1])) for x, y in enumerate(groupby(df.Val, key=lambda x: x > 0))))

bins = [[], []]
for _, frame in df.groupby('grouper'):
    if (frame.Val == 0).all():
        bins[0].append(frame.iloc[:, :-1])
    else:
        bins[1].append(frame.iloc[:, :-1])


print(bins)
```

Should yield the following list:

```
# [[                 Time  Val
# 0 2017-06-29 17:48:00    0
# 1 2017-06-29 17:49:00    0,                  Time  Val
# 5 2017-06-29 17:53:00    0
# 6 2017-06-29 17:54:00    0
# 7 2017-06-29 17:55:00    0
# 8 2017-06-29 17:56:00    0
# 9 2017-06-29 17:57:00    0], [                 Time  Val
# 2 2017-06-29 17:50:00    1
# 3 2017-06-29 17:51:00    2
# 4 2017-06-29 17:52:00    3]]
```

The idea here is that you are applying `run-length encoding` on column `Val`, which basically means that ***you compute the lengths of runs of equal values***. The output of this process is saved in a new column called `grouper`. It is this column that is used to group your initial dataframe. Once the grouping is done, then you move forward with placing the separate dataframes in your `bins` list with a `for-loop`.

While I cannot vouch for the speed, I believe this idea gets you your desired output very easily. You could try to implement the `run-length encoding` idea with `numpy` for a little bit of speed.

#### Edit:

As mentioned, when `groupby(df.Val, key=lambda x: x > 0)` is called while `df.Val` contains null values, the condition is not met because `NaN > 0` should return False. That being the case, the grouping becomes faulty, leading to an unexpected output. Since the goal is distinguish between values equal to `0` and those that are not, then you can change the function passed to the `key` parameter when grouping with `groupby(df.Val, key=lambda x: x == 0)`. The following is almost the same as what's above, with the only exception being `==` instead of `>`:

```
d = {'Time': [Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:48:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:49:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:50:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:51:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:52:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:53:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:54:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:55:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:56:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:57:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:58:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-29 17:59:00')],
 'Val': [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, None, 0, 0, 0, 0, None]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)


df['grouper'] = reduce(list.__add__, ([x]*len(list(y[1])) for x, y in enumerate(groupby(df.Val, key=lambda x: x == 0))))

bins = [[], []]
for _, frame in df.groupby('grouper'):
    if (frame.Val == 0).all():
        bins[0].append(frame.iloc[:, :-1])
    else:
        bins[1].append(frame.iloc[:, :-1])

# [[                 Time  Val
# 0 2017-06-29 17:48:00  0.0
# 1 2017-06-29 17:49:00  0.0,                  Time  Val
# 5 2017-06-29 17:53:00  0.0,                   Time  Val
# 7  2017-06-29 17:55:00  0.0
# 8  2017-06-29 17:56:00  0.0
# 9  2017-06-29 17:57:00  0.0
# 10 2017-06-29 17:58:00  0.0], [                 Time  Val
# 2 2017-06-29 17:50:00  1.0
# 3 2017-06-29 17:51:00  2.0
# 4 2017-06-29 17:52:00  3.0,                  Time  Val
# 6 2017-06-29 17:54:00  NaN,                   Time  Val
# 11 2017-06-29 17:59:00  NaN]]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Speed is pretty damn good, though it might be worth adding to your answer (based on my experience) that if the `Val` field you use contains any `NaN` values, it can cause inconsistencies in the output. E.g. for two datasets where `Val == 0` for all rows, I experienced the following: for the first dataset `len(bin[0]) == 1` and `len(bin[1]) == 0` (as expected), but for the other `len(bin[0]) == 0` and `len(bin[1]) == 1` (the inverse of what was expected). The latter occurred when a `df.Val` contained `NaN` values.

Comment: @RockJake28, that's a very good point and one I failed to see previously. A quick fix would be `groupby(df.Val, key=lambda x: x == 0)` instead of `groupby(df.Val, key=lambda x: x > 0)` when generating the `grouper` column.

Comment: Also, for anyone looking at this in the future, `df.ix()` needs to changed to either `df.loc` or `df.iloc()` (I'm not 100% sure as to which) as `ix()` is deprecated.